# Confused with "do" variables in Racket code

Tags: variables, scope, racket, do-loops

Don't understand why 
    "a" 
and 
    "b"
work in the code ? should we define var 
    "a"
and 
    "b" 
before 
    "do" 
?

```
(define v1 3)
(define v2 2)
(do ((a 1 (+ a v1))
     (b 2 (+ b v2)))
  ((>= a b) (if (= a b) 'YES 'NO)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `(do` the local variables for the do loop are defined:

- `(a 1 (+ a v1))` meaning: define local loop variable `a` with starting value `1` and assigning `(+ a v1)` to `a` at the beginning of a new round
- `(b 2 (+ b v2))` meaning: define local loop variable `b` with starting value `2` and assigning `(+ b v2)` to `b` at the beginning of a new round

So, `a` and `b` are defined in the `do` loop.

Comment: welcome! I recommend you the Hyperspec to consult always when you have syntactic problems like this :) http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm

Comment: nice ! racket doc doesn't have much detail like it, but that's common lisp, how could I know it works for scheme or racket as well ?

Comment: the examples are mostly very helpful in the hyperspec

Answer (score 0):

There are no control flow operations other than procedure calls. 
`do` is just a macro. The R5RS report gives an implementation:

```
(define-syntax do
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((do ((var init step ...) ...)
       (test expr ...)
       command ...)
     (letrec
         ((loop
           (lambda (var ...)
             (if test
                 (begin
                   (if #f #f)
                   expr ...)
                 (begin
                   command
                   ...
                   (loop (do "step" var step ...)
                         ...))))))
       (loop init ...)))
    ((do "step" x)
     x)
    ((do "step" x y)
     y)))
```

Your code turns into something like this:

```
(let loop ((a 1) (b 2))
  (if (>= a b)
      (if (= a b) 'YES 'NO)
      (loop (+ a v1) (+ b v2))))
```

Comment: nice ! that's helpful !